# SQL Max Degree of parallelism value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server-2012, sql-query

Recently we had to reconfigure entire SQL(SharePoint) server due to catastrophic failure in out storage components. While we have done that successfully, we have forgot to turn on the MAX Degree of parallelism to 1 in the SQL instance. Due to this I am seeing some random issues in the SharePoint Logs and CA asking us to change the value to 1.

As the farm is in production, I would like to know whether changing this value to 1 will cause any problem to Instance?

SharePoint Server 2013 is current version which we are using.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Server MAXDOP (MAX Degree of parallelism ) should be changed to 1 for SharePoint.

If any other applications are using SharePoint, this will limit the degree of parallelism for those applications, and therefore may impact the performance of the applications.

If you do not change the degree of parallelism, some actions in SharePoint may not be possible, for example, trying to create a new database will not be possible if the MAX degree of parallelism is not set to 1. See [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rcormier/2012/10/24/you-shall-configure-your-maxdop-when-using-sharepoint-2013/) for further information.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Andy.. My confusion was about the issues that may arise if i change the value. I want to know if the SP databases will get corrupted if i make the change in production instance which is already in use.

Comment: No, you should change the value even if you've already deployed the farm.